Import could not be resolved by any source; ModuleNotFound
I cannot make migrations due to the issue stated in the title.

All of the files shown in explorer have the same issue.
I didn't notice the issue until I went to make migrations for polls and returned the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'; polls.apps is not a package
I am doing the basic Django tutorial and this is the only issue I have had so far.
 I tried changing polls.apps.PollsConfig in the installed apps section to have django at the end (as it is shown in the console error).

 I tried changing polls\apps.py to 'from mysite.apps' which shows the same error, as well as 'from polls.apps' which shows a circular error.  I did this to see if VSCode would remove the underline showing there was no longer an error.  'from polls.apps' did remove the underline, however when making the migration it showed a circular error in powershell. 

 I'm figuring on this being a simple beginner error and am hoping someone will know what the issue is at a glance.  It wouldn't bother me at all to start this over and do it again but since I clearly made an error and therefor likely didn't understand something it would be very cool to know what that was and possibly gain some insight.

It may be important to mention I am using the version of powershell that comes with windows 11 and I am not using it from VSCode; I am only using VSCode for its browser/to write the code.
Below are pictures with the requested information:
pip freeze

polls\apps.py

traceback

excerpt from settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]


Did you install the Django

Show us the contents of polls/apps.py.  Also please show the full error traceback message.

post was updated with more information.

Show us the value of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Also, please post code and errors as plain text.  Posting as an image just makes it harder for us to help.

from now on I will only post code and errors as plain text per instruction

i added a comma after the added app and the migration completed successfully.  cant believe i missed that.  thanks for taking a look

Please show how you imported the module.

@AtreusArcheus You don't just have to keep it in mind for the future! You can [edit] your posts (and other people's as well) to improve them even after they've been posted.

You are missing a comma after the first item in your list. To fix your error, add a comma after your polls app like this:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig', # here 
    ... 
]

Note that INSTALLED_APPS should have a list of strings designating all applications that are enabled in your Django installation. Lists in Python contains items separated by commas between square brackets.
See the docs.
